# How many pages can I print at once on my HP OfficeJet safely?

Tags: printing, printer

I have an HP Officejet Pro 8600 Plus. I've installed a fresh high-yield ink cartridge and have been printing about 1500 pages a day, but I'm wondering now if that's a good idea. Only about 30 words are being printed on each page (adding to a pre-printed document), and over the course of a few days about 10,000 pages are planned to be printed. Printing of this volume is only needed about once a year.

Will I be able to use this printer for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only 30 words (150-200 characters) printing on each page, there's nothing to worry about relative to overtaxing anything on the printer.  If you print those 1500 daily pages over an 8 hour shift, that's only about 250 pages per hour, or about 4 1/4 per minute.  That printer is significantly faster than that page rate, especially with the tiny amount you're actually printing on each page.

I wouldn't expect any problems, but I would recommend you use the printer a little, at least once a week during the "off season" when you're not printing 250 pages per hour -- just to keep moving parts from seizing, and to ensure you don't get an unpleasant surprise next year when the printing season rolls around.

Comment: I've only been noticing about a .6% error rate so far so I felt pretty good about it, but just wanted to make sure. This puts me at ease a bit. Thank you! ^_^

Comment: That error level, if largely jams, is most likely due to irregularities in the paper rather than anything to do with the printer itself.

Comment: Yesterday there were no jams, today there were several. Pages lost today is about 2.2%. The actual error rate is lower because each time 2 or 3 pages got damaged. Still not bad, but noticeably increased. The paper is roughly 6x9in.

Comment: I used to repair printers/copiers (ugh). Your biggest issue is going to be paper dust. Specifically, that dust getting on the rollers causing them to have less friction (some have a special texture that might even be directional to help grab paper). You can clean the rollers with some alcohol, although it may degrade the material after some time. Also, there are paper sensors in the paper path so the printer can detect jams and such. If the dust gets on those, it may either think paper is present where it shouldn't be, or not detect it where it is (causing a "false jam")

Comment: You should be able to find replacement rollers.

Comment: Daily cleaning (blowing out dust as well as wiping the rollers with a damp, lint-free wipe) will solve most of the dust problems.  Careful loading can cut down on the real jams.  And, as noted, parts are available for many printers (others, especially print-only models as opposed to all-in-ones, cost so little up front that it makes more sense to get a new one when wear starts to affect reliability).